# virtualbox virtual machine on usb flash drive

Tags: linux, virtualbox

In my Linux class, we created virtual machines on flash drives, and installed Lubuntu on them.  We are supposed to be able to now run our virtual machines on any computer with oracle vm installed, at least that was the impression I got.  But I cannot run my virtual machine on my home computer.

Is there a trick to accomplishing this?  I'm supposed to send an email from my virtual machine as part of an assignment.

I'm about to make a new one, with vbox portable installed on the flash drive, but I read that you can only run on a computer in which you have administrative rights, so not the computers we use at school.

Anyways, what is the solution?  How do you create a virtual machine on a flash drive and run it on a computer you don't have administrative rights on, which has oracle virtualbox installed, and also be able to run it on your computer at home?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to just double-click the _vm_name.vbox_ XML configuration (for Windows hosts anyway) stored on your flash drive and it will register the VM with VirtualBox and launch it. As a fallback, you should be able to just drag and drop that same .vbox config file on the VirtualBox GUI to register the VM. This is true for all the VirtualBox 4.x versions.

You are correct that you will either need VirtualBox installed or admin privileges to run the portable version. What specifically is the problem you are having at home? What operating system do you have? what version of VirtualBox?

Comment: I have windows 7 at home.  On my usb stick I only have .vmdk files.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  I feel kind of stupid.  Just had to create a new machine with existing hard drive.